# Missing attachments using Mailkit

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

When I receive a mail with attahcment(s) from Exchange via IMAP protocol using MailKit, it's missing the attachment.
When I do:

```
string.Format("Mail has {0} attachments", mime.Attachments.Count())
```

It report "0", even tho that the mail itself contain a attachment (I see the attachment if I open it in Outlook client), and when I activate the IMAP protocol logging, it's clearly that it contains an attachment:

```
S: X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
...
S: Content-Type: message/rfc822
S: Content-Disposition: attachment;
S:  creation-date="Thu, 07 Jan 2016 09:16:53 GMT";
S:  modification-date="Thu, 07 Jan 2016 09:16:53 GMT"
...
S: X-MS-Has-Attach:
...
```

Funny thing is the "S: X-MS-Has-Attach:" header in the attachment part, within the same package from server.

Is this a known issue, and how do I fix it so I won't miss the attachments in these cases? It only seems to happen on some mails and occur randomly.

Using:
MailKit 1.0.14.0
MimeKit 1.0.13.0

I discovered that there are new update, but I won't really update if this won't solve the issue anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the version of MimeKit that you are using, `MimeMessage.Attachments` is `IEnumerable<MimePart>`, but a message/rfc822 part is represented by a `MessagePart` which does not subclass `MimePart`, it subclasses `MimeEntity` (which is the base class for `MimePart`).

In newer versions, `MimeMessage.Attachments` is `IEnumerable<MimeEntity>` instead, and so will include your message/rfc822 attachment.

You can work around this in your version of MimeKit by using the `BodyParts` property instead of the `Attachments` property.

Comment: The update seems to fix the problem. At least I can see Attachment count correctly now. Cheers